# \u0000 cannot be converted to text in django/postgreSQl

Tags: django, postgresql

i have a project with django .on the host when i want to upload an image sometime error occurred(problem with specific images)! the below show how i resize uploaded images:

```
def save_files_to_media(request, is_public=False, klass=None, conversation=None):
    from apps.file.models import File
    fs = FileSystemStorage()

    file_items = {}
    for data_item in request.data:
        file_match = re.search('^fileToUpload\[(\d+)\]$', data_item)
        if file_match and file_match.groups():
            item_index = file_match.groups()[0]

            if item_index not in file_items:
                file_items[item_index] = {}

            file_items[item_index]['file_to_upload'] = request.data[data_item]
        else:
            optimize_match = re.search('^optimizeType\[(\d+)\]$', data_item)
            if optimize_match and optimize_match.groups():
                item_index = optimize_match.groups()[0]

                if item_index not in file_items:
                    file_items[item_index] = {}

                file_items[item_index]['optimize_type'] = request.data[data_item]

    files = []
    for file_item_key in file_items:
        input_file = file_items[file_item_key]['file_to_upload']
        # TODO: checking validation. if input_file.name is not exist

        optimize_type = file_items[file_item_key].get('optimize_type')

        file_uuid = str(uuid4())
        if is_public:
            orig_filename, file_ext = splitext(basename(input_file.name))
            directory_name = join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_uuid)
            filename = file_uuid + file_ext
        else:
            directory_name = join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_uuid)
            mkdir(directory_name)
            filename = input_file.name

        filepath = join(directory_name, filename)
        fs.save(filepath, input_file)

        is_optimized = False
        if optimize_type == 'image':
            is_success, filepath = image_optimizer(filepath)
            filename = basename(filepath)
            is_optimized = is_success

        file_obj = File(
            orig_name=filename,
            uuid=file_uuid,
            md5sum=get_md5sum(filepath),
            filesize=get_filesize(filepath),
            meta=get_meta_info(filepath),
            is_optimized=is_optimized,
            creator=request.user
        )
        if is_public:
            file_obj.is_public = True
        else:
            file_obj.klass = klass
            file_obj.conversation = conversation

        file_obj.save()
        files.append(file_obj)
    return files
```

here is the error i got with some images:

```
unsupported Unicode escape sequence
LINE 1: ..., 'ada90ead20f7994837dced344266cc51', 145216, '', '{"FileTyp...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  \u0000 cannot be converted to text.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ...ecTimeDigitized": 506779, "MakerNoteUnknownText":
```

its funny that in my local but not in host. for more information i must tell you guys my postgreSQL version is `11.3` and host postgreSQl is `9.5.17` . where you think is problem? as error it's seems for postgreSQL. thank you

Comment: I don't known exactly where your json is, but replacing `'\u0000'` in the json data should fix it. `json_data.repalce('\u0000' , ' ')` like so.

Comment: thank you. can you tell me where is the problem related? it's about postgre or response json or....? because in my local that is work but in host not.